# Looping Through an Array of Characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, textbox, toggle

I would like to loop an array for a specific set of characters that is constantly changing. From there on I want to toggle case the letters, and I've been told to use this specific code but I can't get it to work. The code MUST loop through an array of characters, where the characters are coming from an "input" textbox. How can I fix this?

*I should mention that I'm doing this for class in high school, so I'm no where near perfect at coding.*

---

```
    <html> 
      <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function toggleCase() { 
        var i = document.getElementById("input").value.length;
        var word = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var chop =new array(i);
        for (a=i; a <= i; a++) {
            character[i] = word.slice(i-1,i)
            if (character[i] == character[i].toUpperCase;){
                character[i] = character[i].toLowerCase();
            }
            else {
                character[i] = character[i].toUpperCase();
            }
        }

        var final

        for (a=i; a <= i; a++) {
            final += character[i];
        }

        document.getElementById("output").value = final
    }
        </script> 
      </head> 
      <body> 
        <p>Enter letters for conversion:</p> 
        <form> 
          <input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="sample" maxlength="10"><br />
          <input type="text" name="output" id="output" value="" /> <br/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="ToggleCase" onClick="toggleCase(this.form)">Toggle Case<br/>
        </form> 
      </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: javascript not java, use correct tags

Comment: you're taking a lot of performance hits for calling `document.getElementById("input")` so many times in that loop.

Comment: you are missing semicolons every where!

Comment: these for loops are just confusing you're using `a` as a counter and referencing with `i`

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle for you to use http://jsfiddle.net/wqbDA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at some api's and howtos but here is your code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggleCase() { 
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var character = new Array(text.length);

  for (i=0, a = text.length; i < a; i++) {
    character[i] = text[i];
    if (character[i] == character[i].toUpperCase){
      character[i] = character[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    else {
      character[i] = character[i].toUpperCase();
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("output").value = character.join('');
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p>Enter letters for conversion:</p> 
<form> 
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="sample" maxlength="10"><br />
<input type="text" name="output" id="output" value="" /> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="ToggleCase" onClick="toggleCase()">Toggle Case<br/>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleCase() { 
   var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
   for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
     str[i] = (str[i]==str[i].toUpperCase() ? str[i].toLowerCase() : str[i].toUpperCase());
   }
   document.getElementById("output").value = str;
}
```

that's a for loop that does the job. and remember `.toUpperCase` and `.toLowerCase` are functions

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the String's split method.

```
var str = 'foo bar baz';
```

The simplest way to convert a string into a char array is by passing an empty string into the split method.

```
var charArray = str.split(''):
// charArray === ['f','o','o' ... 'b','a','z'];
```

Also a FYI, passing a space character into split will give you an array of words.

```
var wordArray = str.split(' ');
// wordArray === ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
```

I'm a little unclear what you have to solve but it looks like you want a function convert upper case letter into lowercase letters and vise versa.

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('someTextBox');
// If you want to be fancy you could use JQuery
// var userInput = $(#someTextBox').value() 

function toggledCase( str ) {

    var characters = str.split('');
    // The split method still uses iteration so should be able to say it 
    // satisfies the argument of looping through each character.  
    // Split just provides a good abstraction to interface with.

    var toggledCharacters = [];
    var i;
    var ch;
    for( i in characters ) {
        // For in loops on strings will return the indexes instead 
        // of the characters
        ch = characters[i];

        if( ch.toUpperCase() === ch ){
            toggledCharacters.push( ch.toLowerCase() );
        } else {
            toggledCharacters.push( ch.toUpperCase() );
        }

        // If you like one-liners, 
        // the conditional if statement could be replace with a ternay statement.

        //  toggledCharacters.push( ( ch.toUpperCase() === ch ) ? 
        //  ch.toLowerCase() : ch.toUpperCase();
    }

    return toggledCharacters;
}
```

My toggledCharacters method only returns an array of characters, so if you want back as a string you could make a for loop;

```
var arr = toggledCharacters('Foo'); // str = 'fOO';
var str = '';  

var i, ch;
for ( i in arr ) {
    str += arr[i]; // += is just a short hand notation of saying 
                   //      str = str + arr[i];
}
```

If you are lazy and like one-liners, take a look at functional programming.  It's kinda out of scope since you are still in High School.

```
var arr = toggledCharacters('Foo'); // str = 'fOO';
var str = arr.reduce( function(str, ch) {
    return str + ch;
} );
```

Anyway, this looks a lot cleaner to me than what the teacher outlined.

```
function toggledCharacters(input) {
    input = input.split('');
    var output = [];

    var i, ch;
    for( i in input ) {
        output.push( ( input[i].toUpper() === input[i] ) ?
            input[i].toLower() : input[i].toUpper()
        );
    }

    return output.reduce( 
        function(str, ch) {
            return str + ch;
        }
    );
}
```

Edit:

Oh, I just notice that nowhere in that code the is the check's box boolean value being evaluated.

```
var checkBox = document.getElementByName('toggle');
var inputTextBox = document.getElementById('input'); 
var outputTextBox = document.getElementById('output');

var result = inputTextBox.value;

if( checkBox.checked ) {
    result = toggleCase( result );
}

outputTextBox.value = result;
```

Oh another FYI since you are a beginner.  Make sure you know to use the browser's console.

If you are on Firefox, grab the firebug app.

Chrome, press Ctrl-Shift-C.

IE has one as well, I just don't care to ever use it.

The console makes it easier to experiment with JS then compared to making html demo page and assuming the code is working as it should.

Plus, these developer tools can show you underlying methods of an object.  It makes for a great and quick way to learn JS.